# How Can I Filter SQL Results Based On Row With Last Timestamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm fairly new to SQL; please forgive the naivete of this question.

Suppose you have a table where each row has the following entries, all of which are varchar(50): DocumentName, DocumentNumber, Status, PreviousUser, NextUser, Timestamp.  Timestamp is such that alphabetical sorting is also chronological.  While each row is unique, you are not guaranteed unique DocumentName and DocumentNumber entries on each row.

I would like to make a query that returns *unique* DocumentName, DocumentNumber, and Status for all documents where the *last* NextUser entry for that DocumentName and DocumentNumber (as measured by the Timestamp) matches a string that I have.  How would I format that as a query?

Here's a sample table with example returns that might help to clarify what I'm asking for.

```
+================+================+============+==============+==========+============+
| DocumentName   | DocumentNumber | Status     | PreviousUser | NextUser | Timestamp  |
+================+================+============+==============+==========+============+
| Change Request | 1              | PROCESSING | SSMITH       | MJONES   | 2020 02 01 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Change Request | 1              | DRAFT      | JDOE         | SSMITH   | 2020 01 01 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Change Request | 1              | COMPLETE   | SSMITH       | NULL     | 2020 02 22 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Change Request | 1              | APPROVAL   | MJONES       | SSMITH   | 2020 02 21 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Change Request | 3              | PROCESSING | JDOE         | SSMITH   | 2020 04 17 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| User Request   | 1              | APPROVAL   | SSMITH       | MJONES   | 2020 01 01 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| User Request   | 1              | REWORK     | MJONES       | SSMITH   | 2020 03 03 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| User Request   | 1              | APPROVAL   | SSMITH       | MJONES   | 2020 03 07 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| User Request   | 7              | DRAFT      | JDOE         | SSMITH   | 2020 03 17 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| User Request   | 7              | APPROVAL   | SSMITH       | MJONES   | 2020 03 19 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Problem Report | 1              | PROCESSING | JDOE         | SSMITH   | 2020 05 03 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Problem Report | 1              | DRAFT      | JDOE         | JDOE     | 2020 05 02 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Problem Report | 9              | COMPLETE   | JDOE         | NULL     | 2020 06 24 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Problem Report | 13             | DRAFT      | JDOE         | SSMITH   | 2020 07 04 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Problem Report | 13             | REWORK     | SSMITH       | JDOE     | 2020 07 17 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

If I want to match JDOE, I should get back one row: ('Problem Report', 13).

If I want to match SSMITH, I should get back two rows: ('Change Request', 3) and ('Problem Report', 1).

If I want to match MJONES, I should get back two rows: ('User Request', 1) and ('User Request', 7).

Please let me know if I've left something ambiguous.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). [mcve].

Comment: I've added it to the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but: storing timestamps (actually dates) in a `varchar` column is  a really, really bad idea. Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model?

Comment: I'm using the NextUser column to determine the user.

I may have a chance to fix the timestamp thing in the future, but not soon.  I'm using MSSQL Server Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you provide the sample data in an insert statement format? For example, ('Change Request', '1', 'PROCESSING', 'SSMITH', 'MJONES', '2020-02-01')

Comment: What do you mean by "sample data"?

Comment: @MattFunke check the dbfiddle link that I have provided in the answer section. You can see in the table schema build and insert I need that information to be formatted in a specific way. B/c it was too much work to do so, I have only provided an example using some of the samples you have listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once you supply the table name:

```
SELECT *
FROM Abc123 AS a
WHERE NextUser = @MyUser
AND 
EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM abc123 AS i
   WHERE a.DocumentName = i.DocumentName
   AND a.DocumentNumber = i.DocumentNumber
   GROUP BY i.DocumentName,
       i.DocumentNumber
   HAVING MAX(i.Timestamp) = a.Timestamp
)
```

This should return records from the table in which the last NextUser to touch the record matches @MyUser.

The inner query identifies the max timestamp for each Document Name & Document Number.  The outer query is then correlated by the Name, Number and Timestamp.  Finally, the outer query result is filtered by your parameter.

This should be sargable and work with any relevant indexes on the table as well.

Comment: That seems to work really, really well!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it  Please mark the answer if that solved it for you.

Comment: You bet.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
Select DISTINCT DocumentName, DocumentNumber, Status
from table_name
WHERE nextuser = 'your string'
  AND timestamp = (Select MAX(timestamp) from table_name)
```

Comment: Not exactly.  That, if I understand things correctly, will only return something if the timestamp matches the very last timestamp in the table.  I'm only interested in the last timestamp for a particular (DocumentName, DocumentNumber) pair.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a window function that will rank the entries based on docName, docNumber, and status as shown below:

```
  SELECT
    docName,
    docNumber,
    status,
    prevU,
    nextU,
    ts,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY
        docName,
        docNumber,
        status
      ORDER BY
        ts desc
    ) rnk
 FROM docs
```

Basically what this does is for each docName, docNumber and status it will return a rank based on the most recent date. For example, based on your sample data, you have 'Change Request' with docNumber as '1' four different times each with a different status. Since the status is unique for those 4 entires, they are ranked as 1. For "User Request" docNumber '1' and status 'APPROVAL' coming in twice, you will see the date with '2020-03-07' ranked as 1 since that is the most recent.

The sample results can be found in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f85e236f8efc698910e628ca01041d27). You can modify this to include all of the sample data to get a better idea of how the ranking is working.

Once you have the full results you can query on the following filter condition:

```
 where rnk = 1 and nextU = 'name'
```

The above filter will return the most recent entries for that specific user. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ac78b8193832f17ceb4a3d0cbba751f)

Also, note I have just changed the column names in my example to make it easier for me.

Another thing, I am not entirely sure of how you need it partitioned, so you can modify that based on your requirements.

If it needs to be based only on docName and docNumber then just remove status column from the partition by clause. Results for this [scenario](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=008dbfc5dc0d1f445d003ca4f0e91855)